# AWS SES Email using boto3 through python lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ses

```
boto3.client('ses').send_email(
        Source = email_from,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                email_to,
            ]
        },
        Message={
            'Subject': {
                'Data': emaiL_subject
            },
            'Body': {
                'Text': {
                    'Data': email_body.format(user_password)
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

I am using boto3 SES, after execution of the above code through lambda function I am getting the following error:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: \"https://email.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/\
```

For Lambda function my region is **ap-southeast-1**

Any Help will be appriciated

Comment: what is in your config file at ~/.aws/config ?

Comment: @Prany I was not using ~/.aws/config. I was writing code into live console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing this, AWS offers its SES service only for 6 regions:

- US East (N. Virginia) `us-east-1`
- US West (Oregon) `us-west-2`
- EU (Ireland) `eu-west-1`
- AP (Mumbai) `ap-south-1`
- AP (Sydney) `ap-southeast-2`
- EU (Frankfurt) `eu-central-1`

Use one of the above as your `AWS_REGION`

```
client = boto3.client('ses',region_name=AWS_REGION)
```

Note: Look for the latest list of regions on AWS [website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/regions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by a hardcode region string **'us-east-1'**

Now I am creating the client as:

```
boto3.client('ses', 'us-east-1')
```

I think this was due to the unavailability of SES in Singapore region.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the status of AWS services and their availability in different regions before using at https://status.aws.amazon.com/.