# Task run by all ec2 instances

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a python scripts that send mail to users, I want to run this scripts by all instances which is in running state at a particular interval of time(decided by task scheduler of instances).

I have not to use AWS Lambda.
Is there any way by which i can do it? Can i use AWS image?

Comment: Yes, though it might be more useful for you to [read through the relevant documentation on this topic for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/), then you may want to refer similar threads such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50692772/aws-ses-email-using-boto3-through-python-lambda-function).

Comment: Hi, any specific reason why this python script has to run on all instances? Are you saying you want it to run a specific time in the day or that it must run a certain duration after an event?

Comment: Script will run at particular interval of time for all running instances.

Comment: I do not want to use Lambda and SNS ([https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/]) .

Comment: My python script can gather particular instance details and can send mail to user. Now, I have to automate this for all running instances and fix task schedule.

Comment: After connecting with a VM of an EC2. I place my script inside it and fix the task scheduler whatever i want. It works perfectly for this instance. Now i wanted to do same operation for all EC2 instances. I do not want to connect all EC2 and place script one by one, Is there any automated way to do this for all?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wish to run a script on multiple Amazon EC2 instances at a particular time.

There are basically two ways to do this:

#### Using `cron` on each instance

Each Amazon EC2 instance can trigger its own script. On Linux, you would use `cron`. On Windows you would define a **Schedule Task**.

#### Running commands using AWS Systems Manager Run Command

If you wish to externally trigger a command on multiple Amazon EC2 instances, you can use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). You will first define the commands to be run, and then nominate the instances on which to run the command. The Run Command will manage the process of running the script, gather the results, retry failures and report the results.

The benefit of using the Run Command is that you can centrally manage the process. It is very easy to edit the script and run it when desired. In contrast, if using `cron` you would need to update the script on every instance.